# Window function filtering

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

It it possible to filter with window functions?

I have the below table

```
ID    AssignedDate    StartDate    EndDate   userid   Role
1     1/1/17            1/1/18      2/1/18     rdsd    Red
1     1/15/17           1/1/18      2/1/18     adfd    Red
* 1     12/15/17          1/1/18      2/1/18     dfge    Red
```

I would like to see one row per ID and a new column called FirstAssgnDate

First - take all assigned Date that happened before the startDate then take the MAX assignedDate when role = REd

Output should be:

Table

```
ID    FirstAssgnDate    StartDate    EndDate   userid   Role
1     12/15/17            1/1/18      2/1/18    dfge    Red
```

*This row should bre returned.
I was thinking something like below?

```
  Select *
  max(assignedDate) Keep(when AssignedDate < StartDate) As FirstAssgnDate
  from tablea
```

Comment: In your sample data, all AssignedDates are before StartDate and all roles are 'Red' so it's a bit hard to tell what you want.

Comment: That's correct, I would like the MAX assigned date that's not >=StartDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so we need to use window function simple aggregate function would work , if you only need to check those records with role as Red and assigneddate < startdate (atleast this is what I understood from your question) we can have these in where clause filters as below :

```
    select id,max(assigneddate),startdate,enddate,userid,role
    from tablea
    where asssigneddate < startdate and 
    role = 'Red'
    group by id,startdate,enddate,userid,role;
```